# Python Zybooks LAB 9.6 - Contact List

Tags: python

Yet again, I do not understand an error I keep encountering. Here is my code:

```
s = input()

name = input()

splits = s.split(" ")

i = 0

for i in range(len(splits)):

   if(splits[i] == name):

       break

print(splits[i+1])
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(splits[i+1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am not sure why [i+1] returns as out of range. What did I screw up this time? I appreciate the help in advance as I don't get much guidance from my instructor or TA. You folks rock here!

Edit: I apologize I did not include a desired outcome.

The input is:
Joe,123-5432 Linda,983-4123 Frank,867-5309

Frank

The output is supposed to be:
867-5309

Comment: did you try to debug your code? try to run your code step by step, even writing it down on a piece of paper would do, given an input, check if your code does what you expect it to. 
you should spot your issues pretty easily imho.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'Hello'
name = 'Goodbye'
splits = s.split() # default value is a single space ['Hello'] - notice the single value

for i in range(1): # because splits has a single item in the list
    if 'Hello' == 'Goodbye':
        break
    
print(splits[i+1]) # this will not work because splits has a single index = 0


# same as

s = [0,1]
print(s[2])
```

I advise to come up with a desired output when you are asking a question on StackOverflow so others will have a better understanding of your problem.

Also, as mentioned by Hossein in the comment, try using `print()` in each line of your code to see if you get what you expect.

-- Update --

```
s_input = 'Joe,123-5432 Linda,983-4123 Frank,867-5309'
to_search = 'Frank'

# split the input
splitted_input = s_input.split()


for item_pair in splitted_input:
    # split the pair by a comma
    pair_split = item_pair.split(',')
    name = pair_split[0]
    number = pair_split[1]
    
    if name == to_search:
        print(name, number)
    
Frank 867-5309
```

The problem you had is that after you split you have 3 elements but I assume you have thought you get 6, 3 pairs for a name and a number, therefore when you try to reach the number you get out of index, you need to split by a comma to separate the people one from another and then split again to separate the number from the name.

But I would suggest to use:

```
def find_number(string_to_search, name_to_find):
    splits = string_to_search.split()
    for item in splits:
        if name_to_find.lower() in item.lower():
            return item.split(',')[1]
        
        
find_number('Joe,123-5432 Linda,983-4123 Frank,867-5309', 'Frank')

# '867-5309'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited to include the input and desired output and am still running into the "index out of range" error.

Comment: Added an update.